# How os fingerprinting works and how to prevent it in browser?

Tags: privacy, fingerprinting, os-fingerprinting

For privacy I always changed my useragent of browser regularly and it used to work. But lately changing useragent alone in browser dosen't prevent os fingerprinting. Tools like [https://browserleaks.com](https://browserleaks.com/) can correctly guess my os eventhough I have used private mode with vpn, changed my useragent, disabled javascript and flash, added adblocker and other types of privacy extensions and manually hardened the browser. Even after this  browserleaks knows my os.

How does os fingerprinting works in browsers and how to prevent it?

Answer (score -1):

Probably you need to combine two methods:

- At application level, for example HTTP, by changing the User-Agent and probably other fields.
- At network level, changing IP TTL, TCP window sizes, and so on

Probably with that should be enough but may be I'm missing some of them

Comment: This unfortunately won't work. In fact, changing your UA (especially if randomly) makes you stand out _far_ more. What you have to do is use a _uniform_ signature, e.g. by using Tor Browser.